# Memory violation: SIGSEGV and 'can't find linker symbol for virtual table...'

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, segmentation-fault, vtable

I struggle with a memory violation error in my C++ code, and it makes me crazy. I have to use some existing classes and they work fine almost everywhere else.

I am trying to make a copy of a custom Array object, than modify inner values later. But there is something wrong with that copy operation...

The symptoms are the following:

- `Segmentation fault` after the copy, but not immediately
- Warning: `can't find linker symbol for virtual table for 'MyClass<T>' value`

`MyClass<T>` has nothing to do with the problematic part, and after searching I found that this error could appear when the **vtable was overwritten** [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695411/warning-cant-find-linker-symbol-for-virtual-table-for-value-xxx-value-using).

The SIGSEGV appears at the end of this snippet:

```
// New boxes based on previous content, so first make a copy
Array<Box> nextBoxes(size);
int ic = followingItems.length();  // Array<int> followingItems() : some item id
for (int b = 0; b < size; ++b) {
    Box box(ic, capacity);
    const Box& oBox = currentBoxes[b];  // Array<Box> currentBoxes(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < ic; ++i) {
        if (oBox[i])
            box.add(i);
    }
    nextBoxes.add(box);
}

createConfig(nextBoxes, nextItems);
...
generateCostMatrix(nextBoxes, costMatrix); // <--[SIGSEGV] without any reason, variables are fine
```

And that's where I am totally lost. I tried to use `std::vector` instead `Array<Box> nextBoxes` but the problem remained, just appeared at a different location.

Here is one from the 'legacy' classes:

```
class Box 
{
    Array<bool> items;  // mask of all tools
    int capacity, itemCount, count;
public:
    Box();
    Box(int num, int cap)
      : items(num), capacity(cap), itemCount(num), count(0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            items.add(false);
    }
    Box(const Box& value){...}
    ~Box(){...}
    ...
```

A tiny debugger info from the crash location:

```
array = new T[maxlen]
// values: array=0x0, maxlen=30, len=0 --> looks OK
```

(somewhere deep in the `Array<T>` class, it doesn't really matter where, because always happens in the line `new` like here, and always without visible reason)

Comment: Start by running in a debugger to catch the crash, and then locate where in your code the crash  happens and examine the values of all involved variables. If you still can't figure it out then at least tell us where the crash happens and the variable values.

Comment: What does add do in the Array template-class

Comment: I extended the question with the crash location and with the definition of  `add()`. Hope you will see what I can't.

Comment: The Array class has a default copy constructor, which makes a shallow copy of the data array. Is that intended behavior? It looks wrong to me - usually if you implement assignment as a deep copy you do the same for the copy constructor. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: No, it has a normal copy constructor. I added it as well.

Comment: `memset(array, 0, maxLen * sizeof(T));` is a bug , you should just use default-initialization instead.

Comment: You probably overwrite array bounds and/or use a dangling reference somewhere. Questions like this should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Work backwards from the bugged code, removing large sections at a time until you have the smallest possible program that still exhibits the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll do the MCVE soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, something escaped my attention...
Over-indexing the array happens mostly when your index is out of range. Sometimes the array is too short, or the index is too long, or you create the wrong sized array. And this last case happened here.

**The reason why I answered this question is that:**

I've seen the quoted warning message, but in a totally different scenario (real linking issue, when a node was actually missing from vtable).  In my case the virtual table was overwritten, and surprise, because of some bad array handling.

> Just for the future googlers, this can useful to debug a SIGSEGV which
>   appears at a weird location.

What I learned:

- always *double-check* the container object (not just the index variable)
- *triple-check* your quoted source when you ask a new question (yes, the question contained a typo in a critical line)

---

And here is the solution, which is not so important, but for completeness...

The value of `ic` was the 'bad guy', one needs to go deep in my project to spot it, but i'll explain it:

```
int ic = followingItems.length(); // where Arra<int> followingItems(x);
```

The `followingItems`is a list of the item **ids**(`Arra<`**int**`>`) which need to be inserted. 
`x` can be in the range `[1, allItemCount]`

In the `Box` class, `Array<bool> items` is a boolean mask which marks whether an item is in the box or not. Obliviously, `items.length() = allItemCount` so:

```
followingItems.length <= allItemCount
```

First, I realized that `ic` was running until `87` instead of `400`. I wanted to copy the full content, but only just the first 87 item was tested and added.
With this in my mind, I spot the main bug:

```
Box box(ic, capacity);
```

Where the first param should be the number of all items, but was 87 instead of 400 again. Well, that's pretty painful...